# google spreadsheet freeze column and row

Tags: google-sheets, frozen-columns

I have google spreadsheet with some schedules.

I froze first 3 lines.

### Question:

How can I froze last column in same sheet?

*Note: want to froze RED area*

### Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Google Spreadsheet doesn't allow freezing by coloumn number, you will have to use app script.

Gsheet - Tools - Script Editor

```js
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("yoursheetname");

 // Freezes the first column
 sheet.setFrozenColumns(1);
}
```

[More here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setFrozenColumns%28Integer%29)

Freezes the given number of columns. If zero, no columns are frozen.

Not underestimating you - but still explaining bit by bit so that if required someone else can use it as well...

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by @Vasim is wrong!

That answer `sheet.setFrozenColumns(X)` refer to total number of rows X to freeze from left end of the sheet.

So answer to your question is YOU CAN'T, right most columns cannot be frozen in GSheets,

hope this helps future interweb jedi!

p.s. (I's sure would like that this feature exists in GS)